# Version of Apache installed on a Debian machine

Tags: apache, debian, version

How can I check which version of Apache is installed on a Debian machine?

Is there a command for doing this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww administration of Apache is fundamental to development for many developers. Currently this page has been viewed 473k times which suggests it is useful. Most of those views will have been by people engaged in programming and development and I expect they found it useful. I am one of them.

Answer (score 427):

Try apachectl -V:

```
$ apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.9 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep 18 2008 21:54:05
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:15
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Compiled using: APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
... etc ...
```

If it does not work for you, run the command with `sudo`.

Comment: Warning: when running Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14, `apache2ctl -V` does not work without root privileges (... and it does not print the version). Whereas it works on Ubuntu 12 with Apache 2.2. Tricky.

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 12.04 and I believe a lot of people are still using Ubuntu 12.04, like me, who don't want to upgrade to 14 yet until all bugs with various software are eliminated complete.y

Comment: Works on `Debian 7.1`

Comment: apachectl -V dosen't work on suse10.04 instead we have to type /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -v to get right answer with root permission

Comment: how to check it in windows? Apache server

Comment: Worked on debian 8. But only for root user.

    `$ whereis apachectl
    apachectl: /usr/sbin/apachectl /user/share/man/man8/apachectl.8.gz`

Comment: Worked fine on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)

Comment: For the cases in which it doesn't work try "dpkg -l | grep apache", which has been posted in another reply below. It is the most accurate way!

Comment: Use the one in /usr/apache2/bin/apachectl . I have several.

Comment: **apachectl -v** is OK!

Comment: Starting from Debian 10 you should run "su -l" before "apachectl -V"

Answer (score 154):

This works for my Debian:

```
$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -v
```

Answer (score 34):

You should use **apache2ctl** -v or **apache2 -v** for newer Debian or Ubuntu distributions.

```
apache:/etc/apache2# apache2ctl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   May 12 2011 11:58:18
```

or you can use **apache2 -V** to get more information.

```
apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   May 12 2011 11:58:18
Server's Module Magic Number: x
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.2.12, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
```

Comment: Either upper -V or lowercase -v is ok but you may need to use sudo unless you're logged in as root.

Answer (score 28):

The command varies depending on how your version of Linux has named the Apache Server.

On Debian and Mac OS:

```
apachectl -v
```

On Red Hat and Amazon's EC2 Linux use:

```
httpd -v
```

On other verisons of Linux try:

```
apache2 -v
```

You can use two different flags:

```
-v # gives you the version number
-V # gives you the compile settings including version number.
```

If you want to run the command with the full directory like user3786265 did but don't know where your apache is located, use the `whereis` command:

```
whereis httpd
```

Comment: Brilliant. Your answer covers the range of server environments one might be trying to find the Apache version within. If it were my question, I'd have marked this as *the answer*. Perhaps the only thing I would suggest adding to your answer, is the common paths. In some environments the command might not be in the $PATH, so people trying these commands may get stuck. e.g. In my Debian enviro, I had to use `$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -v` because just `$ apache2 -v` returns `command not found`. This command will help users locate path to apache, if required: `ps -ef | grep apache`

Comment: `apache2 -v` also works on Debian (at least [Debian 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline) (Jessie) on Raspberry Pi).

Answer (score 25):

I am using [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) and the following command works:

```
httpd -V
```

Answer (score 18):

I think you have to be sure what type of installation you have binary or source.
To check what binary packages is installed: with root rights execute following command:

```
dpkg -l |grep apache2
```

result should be something like:

```
dpkg -l |grep apache2
```

```
ii  apache2                               2.4.10-10+deb8u8                      amd64        Apache HTTP Server
ii  apache2-bin                           2.4.10-10+deb8u8                      amd64        Apache HTTP Server (modules and other binary files)
ii  apache2-data                          2.4.10-10+deb8u8                      all          Apache HTTP Server (common files)
ii  apache2-doc                           2.4.10-10+deb8u8                      all          Apache HTTP Server (on-site documentation)
```

To find version you can run :

```
apache2ctl -V |grep -i "Server version"
```

result should be something like:
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Comment: Importantly, this answer also shows the SUB version - 2.4.48 on certian Debian installs also has back-ported security fixes from apache's main 2.4.51.   This method shows the version as `2.4.48-3.x` for example, not just `2.4.48` which is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 16):

Try it with sudo

```
apachectl -V
-bash: apachectl: command not found

sudo apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Debian)
Server built:   Aug 12 2013 18:20:23
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
  forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
bla bla....
```

Comment: This won't work if there are currently syntax error in your configuration files

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the package manager directly:

```
dpkg -l | grep apache
```

This isn't focused on *just version number*, but it will make a broader search, which will give you other useful information, like module versions.

Comment: The restriction to apache may be passed to dpkg directly. For an automated interpretation you also need a single value rather than a list, and you should not have the "uninstalled" apache2-* packages shown. Please also consider
`dpkg -l apache2 | grep ^ii | awk '{print $3}' | cut -f1 -d-`or 
`dpkg -l "apache2*" | grep ^ii | awk '{print $3}' | cut -f1 -d- | head -n 1`.

Answer (score 6):

For me this works on [Debian 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline) (Squeeze):

> Linux www809 2.6.26-2-xen-686 #1 SMP Wed Sep 21 09:56:47 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

I had to go to the right path:

```
/usr/local/apache/bin** $ **./apachectl -v
```

> ./apachectl: line 71: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted 
>   Server version: Apache/**2.2.21** (Unix) 
>   Server built:   Dec 17 2011 19:57:53

Answer (score 6):

Another way round to check a package (including Apache) installed version on Debian-based system, we can use:

```
apt-cache policy <package_name>
```

e.g. for Apache

```
apt-cache policy apache2
```

which will show something like (look at the `Installed` line):

```
$ apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.9
  Version table:
     2.2.22-1ubuntu1.9 0
        500 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.22-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried running the command "httpd -V" and "apachectl -V", but I could not execute and was getting the error:

> -ksh: php: not found [No such file or directory]

Then I tried another way. I went to the Apache directory on my server and then tried executing the command:

```
./apachectl -v
```

This worked for me and returned the output:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.20 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep  6 2012 17:22:16
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

1. You can use `apachectl -V` or `apachectl -v`. Both of them will return the Apache version information!

   ```js
       xgqfrms:~/workspace $ apachectl -v

       Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
       Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04


       xgqfrms:~/workspace $ apachectl -V

       Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
       Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04
       Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:27
       Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
       Compiled using: APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
       Architecture:   64-bit
       Server MPM:     prefork
         threaded:     no
           forked:     yes (variable process count)
       Server compiled with....
        -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
        -D APR_HAS_MMAP
        -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
        -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
        -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
        -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
        -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
        -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
        -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
        -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
        -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
        -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
        -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
        -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
        -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
        -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
   ```
2. You may be more like using `apache2 -V` or `apache2 -v`. It seems easier to remember!

   ```js
       xgqfrms:~/workspace $ apache2 -v

       Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
       Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04


       xgqfrms:~/workspace $ apache2 -V

       Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
       Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04
       Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:27
       Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
       Compiled using: APR 1.5.1-dev, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
       Architecture:   64-bit
       Server MPM:     prefork
         threaded:     no
           forked:     yes (variable process count)
       Server compiled with....
        -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
        -D APR_HAS_MMAP
        -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
        -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
        -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
        -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
        -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
        -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
        -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
        -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
        -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
        -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
        -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
        -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
        -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
        -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

For me `apachectl -V` did not work, but `apachectl fullstatus` gave me my version.

Comment: 'apachectl -v' works for me on Mac, CentOS and Ubuntu. Which distro were you running on? apachectl fullstatus needs mod_status to make this work. So it's not universal solution either.

Comment: `apachectl fullstatus` did not work for me. I got `/usr/sbin/apachectl: 101: /usr/sbin/apachectl: www-browser: not found 'www-browser -dump http://localhost:80/server-status' failed.` (Debian 8 - Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi). However, `apachectl -V` did work.

Answer (score 3):

Some installations of Apache are fubar (think Oracle's packaging of it, OHS) and do not understand the -V flag, nor can be invoked directly without running into missing library errors.

Easiest way is to use the `strings` command (part of `binutils`) on the httpd binary and grep for a string that might resemble a version. For example, assuming your `httpd` binary is under directory `/foo/bar`:

```
$ strings /foo/bar/httpd  | grep 2.2
GLIBC_2.2.5
Oracle-HTTP-Server/2.2.22 (Unix)
Success_Accepted_202
202 Accepted
```

Most binaries (not all) contain their version (at least their major version) as static strings. This is my go-to way to get versions (or to corroborate what a binary's help message matches what reality on the ground truly is.)

Comment: Isn't `httpd` required to be in the current directory for this to work?

Comment: This helped me find out my previous version on my mounted old root from within the new Ubuntu installation. Worth mentioning: "strings" is part of package "binutils"

Comment: @PeterMortensen, yep. I guess my example assumed httpd would be in the current directory (and that the reader would  infer that from the example and adjust as required.) *I'm editing my answer now to reflect that*.

Comment: @Zefiro, thanks for the heads up. I'll update my answer to mention binutils.

Answer (score 2):

Or, less directly:

`nmap -A localhost -p 80`

Comment: If apache is configured not to add version information to HTTP headers, you won't find anything.

Comment: nmap may not be installed (e.g. on a Raspberry Pi): `-bash: nmap: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

Surely typing */usr/sbin/apache2 -v* into the shell is the best and quickest way to go, by the way here's another option, just in case there's PHP too in your server and you're interested into gathering Apache version (and much more infos) in quick programmatical steps.

Just make an **info.php** file in your Apache web root folder (or whatever you like)  and write these inside it:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Now go to *yoursite.com/info.php* (or *localhost/info.php* for local machines).

You'll see your Apache version in *PHP Variables* section, here's an example:

[phpinfo() example dump page](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTIdelGpFE4FuEUbd7K2fuvCmFzcPEhu_T1kmOYnSaCeNBNEce)

Also, please notice that these steps obviously apply to **any web server** with PHP integration, so it's not limited to Apache and once created that page could be handy while developing (just don't forget to remove it on production environments!!)

Answer (score 1):

```
dlocate -s apache2 | grep '^Version:'
```

Answer (score 0):

works in debian 11 bullseye

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -v
```